# binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::unique_ptr<char [],std::default_delete<_Ty>>'

Tags: c++, winforms, c++11

I have this check and when I'm trying to get the username, it says there is no acceptable conversion from Unique_ptr to CString.

Here is my code:

```
if (tsvn_creds.size() == 1)
    {
        std::map<CStringA,Creds>::iterator it = tsvn_creds.begin();
        if (tsvn_creds.find(it->first) != tsvn_creds.end())
        {
            Creds cr = tsvn_creds[it->first];
            user_name = cr.GetUsername();
        }
    }
```

Where GetUsername is:

```
std::unique_ptr<char[]> GetUsername() { return CStringUtils::Decrypt(username); }

CString user_name = NULL;
```

I need user_name as CString because at some point I need to append it to a CString message.

What's wrong with the way I have it setup above?

Here is the error I get:

```
Error   C2679   binary '=': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::unique_ptr<char [],std::default_delete<_Ty>>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

EDIT:

I tried this solution as told in the comments:

```
user_name = *(cr.GetUsername());
```

but I get the error "illegal indirection"

Comment: I think the line `if (tsvn_creds.find(it->first) != tsvn_creds.end())` is redundant.

Comment: `user_name` is `CString`, `GetUserName` returns `unique_ptr`. Classes are completely different. How do you think this will work?

Comment: It's a pointer to an array of chars like a string. Could you explain further what you mean? Thanks.

Comment: This `return CStringUtils::Decrypt(username);` actually returns a unique_ptr ? If so you just need to dereference GetUserName: `*(cr.GetUsername());`

Comment: I'm going to rebuild my solution but so far it says, no operator '*' matches these operands. It won't allow me to deference the pointer. Is it possible I'm missing a library reference?

Comment: @old_mountain It says illegal indirection next to that line and if I hover over the red error, it says what I wrote above.

Comment: @KalaJ, you need to make sure to always update your question according to your latest edits.

Comment: what does CStringUtils::Decrypt(username); return?

Comment: It returns a type of std::unique_ptr<char[]>

Comment: Would return std::move(CStringUtils::Decrypt(username)); work?

Comment: Are you writing CStringUtils, or are you using some third party lib?

Comment: @AdiLevin, I believe it is a third party library. I am working with open source project TortoiseSVN that uses StringUtils.

Comment: @Andrej no I still get illegal indirection message.

Comment: If CString is essentially a dressed up char array you will need to copy the contents to it. I'm not sure about the implementation or assignment operator overloading for CString. For a vanilla std::string you could probably do something like cppStrUserName = std::string(cr.GetUsername().get());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root of your problem is probably the CString type; the error message you get is saying that the implementer(s) of CString didn't define an `operator=` that assigns a CString object from a `unique_ptr<char[]>`.

Based on some quick Googling, I'm guessing your CString type is [this one](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300688(v=vs.60).aspx) because it's from a Microsoft library and you say you're using WinForms. According to the documentation, you can only assign a CString from a raw pointer to a `char` array, that is, `const unsigned char*`. So to assign the result of `GetUsername()` to your CString `user_name`, you need to get the underlying raw pointer from the `unique_ptr`:

```
user_name = cr.GetUsername().get()
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the reason! Thank you so much!

Comment: Actually `user_name = cr.GetUsername().get()` is fine but `const unsigned char* raw_str_ptr = cr.GetUsername().get(); user_name = raw_str_ptr;` is entirely broken, because in the latter the `unique_ptr` will be destroyed before the assignment occurs.